# How do I answer a question like "What kind of activities are in Part C?"?

Tags: word-usage, writing

I am reading a textbook for improving my reading skills.

The title of the book is

> "*READING CONNECTIONS - HIGH INTERMEDIATE*".

This book is divided into four units. From unit one to unit four.

Each unit has four parts. From part A to part D.

Each part C has the same title

```
PART C DOING THE UNIT TASK
```

and the same subtitle

> "**Building Your Vocabulary: Summary"**

But each part C has different content.

Each part D has the same title

```
PART D EXPANSION ACTIVITIES
```

But each part D has different content as well.

In brief, the format is like

```
PART C    DOING THE UNIT TASK
```

> **Building Your Vocabulary: Summary**

....contents are here....

```
PART D    EXPANSION ACTIVITIES
```

> Applying Your Knowledge

....contents are here....

> The Electronic Link

....contents are here....

> For More Information

....contents are here....

> Essay Questions

....contents are here....

As a reader, how do I answer a question like the one above in formal way.

Thank you for your reading.

Comment: Does Part C always have one subsection with the title "Building Your Vocabulary: Summary"?

Comment: Yes, Part C always has one subsection titled "Building Your Vocabulary: Summary". This title is just next below "DOING THE UNIT TASK".

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I was wondering if Part C always has *only* one subsection. If that's the case. Answering "What kind of activities are in Part C?" with "It's about building vocabulary" (but makes it more formal, if you want something dry and formal). If Part C has more than one subsection but the subsections are always the same, then you can answering your question by listing those subsections. If the subsections keep varying (which is unlikely, I believe), you can resort to the title of Part C itself, i.e., "Part C is about doing the unit task." (whatever that means).

Comment: It is not the case that "Part C has more than one subsection but the subsections are always the same". Only Part D has more than one subsections. The number of which is four. Thank you @DamkerngT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am reading your description correctly, it seems that Part C is about

> Building Your Vocabulary

whereas Part D is about taking the learned vocabulary and augmenting it.

Comment: Part C has the activity of "Building Your Vocabulary"... Do I write the answer in a formal way?